# Group by WEEKNUM in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm using query for getting the weeknum from column Date (J) and sum the cost here is the formula

```
=QUERY(J4:K, "SELECT WEEKNUM(J), SUM(K) WHERE J IS NOT NULL GROUP BY WEEKNUM(J) LABEL WEEKNUM(J) 'Week', SUM(K) 'Total'")
```

I tried using MONTH instead of WEEKNUM and it run perfectly, I really don't know where the error might be

sample file : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GO-BwaEWOSf1AnR7rKOMYcpZ_12crehiSJTkFVOOqx8/edit?usp=sharing

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uYlr.png]

---

update :
[image]

why there's a gap?

Comment: Share the sample file.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GO-BwaEWOSf1AnR7rKOMYcpZ_12crehiSJTkFVOOqx8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WEEKNUM` does **not exist in `QUERY`**
Instead you can try the following

```
=QUERY(INDEX(IF(A72:A86="",, {WEEKNUM(A72:A86),B72:C86})), "your query here using Col1, sum(Col3) etc")
```

### EDIT

Just checked your sheet.
Try this query in your formula

```
=QUERY(INDEX(IF(A2:A22="",, {WEEKNUM(A2:A22),B2:C22})), 
         "Select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null 
          group by Col1 label Col1 'week', sum(Col2) 'sum/week' ")
```

*(**Do** adjust the formulae according to your ranges and locale)*

Comment: Done, it work but why there's a gap using that formula

Comment: What do you mean gap?

Answer (score 1):

`WEEKNUM()` is not recognized by `QUERY()` as SQL function. You may try-

```
=QUERY({INDEX(WEEKNUM(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)))),B2:INDEX(B2:B,COUNTA(A2:A))},
"select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1 label Col1 'Week', sum(Col2) 'Sum'")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach `non-query based`

```
={"Week","Sum";index(map(unique(weeknum(filter(A2:A,A2:A<>""))),lambda(z,{z,sumif(weeknum(A:A),z,B:B)})))}
```

[image]